# How to make dependency between 2 services on 2 different Centos host without big statck?

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, centos

I have two servers :

- On the first one there is a tomcat that contains my application (Spring boot)
- On the second sever, there is my database server (MySQL)

How to be robust when the tomcat start while MySQL server is not ready? 
In fact I got this trouble during a power failure and the two services start at the same time, finally tomcat failed.

What is an elegant way to manage this problematic of dependencies between services on different hosts ? Is there a native way in unix for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exist answers to your question.
Links:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433113/how-do-you-use-systemd-to-ensure-remote-database-is-available
- https://serverfault.com/questions/867830/systemd-start-service-only-after-dns-is-available

Basically you need to check is mysql answered on the needed port.
So you can modify tomcat systemd unit file with construction like this:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'until host example.com; do sleep 1; done'
```

This will be work on the hosts with systemd.

In general you will be need to create simple script which try connect to the remote database and if it's successful return exit code 0